# mysql sntax error using sqldatasource in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql

Hi I keep getting this error using a sqldatasource in asp.net, I can connect and see mysql schema and it lists everything fine but every query I test is returned with an error even the manualy inputted ones.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio IDE doesn't supports schemas yet, so you would need to manually Pre-pend Table's Schema name in the Query.

Comment: What like SELECT * FROM 'gymwebsite2','User'; gymwebsite2 being the schema? Tryed that same result

Comment: did you used a comma (,) there or it was a mistake.. anyway try this with a dot (.) in between |  `SELECT * FROM [gymwebsite2].[User]`

Comment: nah doesnt work either, how do I get an odbcdatasource in my toolbox for vs2010? I see no option for it

Comment: In general you should use the native ADO.Net MySql drivers available here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.2.html. These offer much better performance and support more features than the generic ODBC driver.

Comment: There is no ODBC datasource (that I know of), you use a SqlDataSource control and an ODBC connection string in your web.config. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35c54x95.aspx Edit: or better yet, use the MySQL-specific drivers Shekhar mentioned!

Comment: does the ado.net driver overwrite the odbc connector? i use alot of odbc connection strings in my work and if the ado is viable for using with sqldatasources then i will install it but not at the expense of having to change every connection string to ado.net